# How to get Command Line info for a process in PowerShell or C#

Tags: c#, powershell, process, command

e.g: if I run `notepad.exe c:\autoexec.bat`,

How can I get `c:\autoexec.bat` in `Get-Process notepad` in PowerShell?

Or how can I get `c:\autoexec.bat` in `Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");` in C#?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: [How to get the command line parameters from a different process](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8efe163b-927e-4895-9983-b8c47b515d7c/how-to-get-the-command-line-parameters-from-a-different-process-in-c)

Comment: its not clear. can u specify more clearly what exactly you are trying to do? @victorwoo

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: If we've started a process and passed some parameters, how to get the command line parameters of the running process by C# or PowerShell?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

In PowerShell you can get the command line of a process via WMI:

```
$process = "notepad.exe"
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" | Select-Object CommandLine
```

Note that you need admin privileges to be able to access that information about processes running in the context of another user. As a normal user it's only visible to you for processes running in your own context.

Comment: There is a permissions aspect to this too. The Powershell process needs to have permissions at least equivalent to the target process. So a regular Powershell session won't be able to get such information for a process running elevated (e.g. as Administrator). in this case, CommandLine (the response) will just be blank.

Comment: @CJBS To be precise you need admin privileges to be able to access that information about processes running in the context of another user. As a normal user it's only visible to you for processes running in your own context.

Comment: The value is still truncated to a certain length of characters. You can work around it by piping the result to "out-string -Width 2000" or something similar.

Comment: Just a general syntax note, you can also use `| where name -eq $process` instead of `-filter` and it compiles the same before execution.  I prefer this way as it's more extensible.

Comment: @mbrownnyc Using `-Filter` does the filtering on the remote host if your run `Get-WmiObject` against remote computers (using the `-ComputerName` parameter), reducing the amount of data that is transferred over the network (thus improving performance). Using `Where-Object` filters locally, after *all* WMI data was fetched from the remote host(s). It doesn't make a difference when running `Get-WmiObject` locally, though, like in this case. Also note that the syntax `where property <op> value` only works in PowerShell v3 or newer. Prior to that you must use `where { $_.property <op> value }`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks for that point!  Very important with get-wmiobject indeed!

Comment: To avoid long line truncation you can also use `| fl` or `| ft -auto` ([from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13735900/344541))

Comment: This didn't take much to figure out, but to save someone a few keystrokes, if you already have the process id (like from looking at CPU usage, etc) you can use `"processid = 1234"` - I use it for seeing which website is going rogue on our server (and there are 200 `w3wp.exe` processes)

Comment: how to I cast the type of "Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject" to int32, provided I selected processid rather than commandline?

Comment: @Sajuuk That has nothing to do with this question or answer. Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 64):

This answer is excellent, however for futureproofing and to do future you a favor, Unless you're using pretty old powershell (in which case I recommend an update!) Get-WMIObject has been superseded by Get-CimInstance [Hey Scripting Guy reference](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/02/08/should-i-use-cim-or-wmi-with-windows-powershell/)

Try this

```
$process = "notepad.exe"
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" | select CommandLine
```

Comment: Note that with `Get-CimInstance Win32_Process`, the `name` includes the .exe extension. That's different from `Get-Process`.

Comment: Or, if you want to use PIDs: get-process node | select id,starttime,name,@{Name="CommandLine";Expr={ $filter = "ProcessId = {0}" -f $_.Id; (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -filter $filter).CommandLine }} | sort starttime | ft -au -wr

Answer (score 16):

If you put the following code in your powershell `$PROFILE` file you can permanently extend the `Process` object class and use the `CommandLine` property:

```
$TypeData = @{
    TypeName   = [System.Diagnostics.Process].ToString()
    MemberType = [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes]::ScriptProperty
    MemberName = 'CommandLine'
    Value = {
        if (('Win32NT' -eq [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Platform)) { # it's windows
            (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $($this.Id)").CommandLine
        } elseif (('Unix' -eq [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Platform)) { # it's linux/unix
            Get-Content -LiteralPath "/proc/$($this.Id)/cmdline"
        } elseif (('MacOSX' -eq [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Platform)) { # it's macos
            # ???
        }
    }
}
Update-TypeData @TypeData -ErrorAction Ignore
```

> NB: `Update-TypeData` is called with `-ErrorAction Ignore` because in pwsh (at least on version 7.3.4), `CommandLine` already exists; `-EA Ignore` suppresses the error. As an alternative, you could check for the property existence, and execute `Update-TypeData` only in the case of missing property.

The scriptblock used as value is taken from what pwsh 7.3.4 **actually** uses internally, adapted also for Windows Powershell (where `$IsWindows`, etc do not exist).

You can get the code in the scriptblock by running the following in pwsh 7.3.4: `(([System.Diagnostics.Process]@{}) | gm | ? { $_.Name -ieq 'commandline' }) | select -expand Definition`.

Then you can reliably query the command line (**iif** you have the correct rights, for the queried process(es), see [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17582576/9156059), [[2]](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/5eb197e2-aeeb-4eb6-9e5b-9f90966e5d79/win32process-commandline-returning-blank-while-im-not-an-admin?forum=ITCG)):

```
get-process notepad.exe | select-object ProcessName, CommandLine
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm using powershell 7.1 and this seems to be built in to the process object now as a scripted property:

```
> (Get-Process notepad)[0].CommandLine
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"
```

Interestingly, you can view its implementation and see that it partially uses the answer from PsychoData:

```
($process | Get-Member -Name CommandLine).Definition
System.Object CommandLine {get=
                        if ($IsWindows) {
                            (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $($this.Id)").CommandLine
                        } elseif ($IsLinux) {
                            Get-Content -LiteralPath "/proc/$($this.Id)/cmdline"
                        }
                    ;}
```

Running Get-Member on a process shows that it is an instance of [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-5.0#properties), but that it has several properties that are scripted.

The other properties are FileVersion, Path, Product, and ProductVersion.

Comment: Appreciated the idea to use `Get-Member` to get more details on how pwsh works. We can also use `$process | Get-TypeData | ConvertTo-Json` for similar reasons.

Comment: I've tried on macOS and indeed the `CommandLine` property is there but its content is always empty

Answer (score 0):

If the command line is long it will be cut with `Select-Object`. To avoid it format that properly:

```
$process = "notepad.exe"
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" | Select-Object CommandLine | Format-Custom
```

The result will be between curly braces:

```
class ManagementObject
{
  CommandLine = "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_11.2112.32.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Notepad\Notepad.exe"
  "C:\Users\sto\Desktop\file.txt"
}
```