# How can I close, in shell scripting, a Windows process locating it by its parameters?

Tags: windows, shell, process

I use to run Python programs via the executable included in CygWin, for example:

```
c:\CygWin\bin\python2.7.exe /usr/local/bin/FunnyProgram.py
c:\CygWin\bin\python2.7.exe /usr/local/bin/BoringWordProcessor.py
```

Note that the `/usr/local...` stuff are the parameters part, not the executable program.
I am making a **Windows shell script** that pretends to **close someone** of them, for example "FunnyProgram.py". But I can not do:

```
taskkill /im "Funny*" /f
```

because all the operating system seems to see is:

```
C:\>tasklist | find "python" /i
python2.7.exe                 5012 Console                    1    13.240 KB
```

And there is no results at all if I do:

```
tasklist | find "Funny" /i
```

Neither can I find it by using **SysInternals PSExec**:

```
C:\>pslist python -x
pslist v1.3 - Sysinternals PsList
Copyright (C) 2000-2012 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
Process and thread information for KENOBI:
Name                Pid      VM      WS    Priv Priv Pk   Faults   NonP Page
python2.7          5012  588464   13240   13416   13556     3458     11  103
 Tid Pri    Cswtch            State     User Time   Kernel Time   Elapsed Time
 580  10       316     Wait:UserReq  0:00:00.062   0:00:00.202    0:23:42.743
2760  11         4   Wait:Executive  0:00:00.000   0:00:00.000    0:23:42.741
 616   8         4     Wait:UserReq  0:00:00.000   0:00:00.000    0:23:42.597
3164  11        49     Wait:UserReq  0:00:00.000   0:00:00.000    0:23:42.460
```

And mostly the same for **SysInternals Handle**:

```
C:\Windows\system32>handle -p "python"
Handle v3.51
Copyright (C) 1997-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
python2.7.exe pid: 5012 KENOBI\Luis
   60: Section       \BaseNamedObjects\cygwin1S5-c5e39b7a9d22bafb\shared.5
   64: Section       \BaseNamedObjects\cygwin1S5-c5e39b7a9d22bafb\S-1-5-21-33151
06853-2407454319-848584108-1000.1
   70: Section       \BaseNamedObjects\cygwin1S5-c5e39b7a9d22bafb\cygpid.5012
   C0: Section       \BaseNamedObjects\cygwin1S5-c5e39b7a9d22bafb\c5e39b7a9d22ba
fb-cons0x240B0C.0
   CC: Section       \BaseNamedObjects\cygwin1S5-c5e39b7a9d22bafb\cygpid.5552
  254: File  (RWD)   C:\Users\Luis
```

How can I **detect the PID** (in order to close it), or at least directly close, some specific program locating it by its parameters?
(I would like to do this in a **Windows shell** script, but **additional command-line utilities** are accepted if needed)

EDIT: Another method not working. If I do `notepad test.txt`, I can find it using PowerShell:

```
$process = "notepad.exe"
gwmi Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" | select CommandLine
```

I save these two lines to "TestNotepad.ps1" and I do:

```
C:\>Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File TestNotepad.ps1
CommandLine
-----------
"C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
"C:\Windows\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE" D:\test.txt
```

But for the file:

```
$process = "python2.7.exe"
gwmi Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" | select CommandLine
```

I just get a simple:

```
C:\>Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File TestPython.ps1
CommandLine
-----------
"C:\CygWin\bin\python2.7.exe"
```

...with no parameters at all. Strange!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17582576/2855568

You can call powershell from a windows shell script.

Comment: Not working, @DeveloperGuo . Added extra info to the original question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Windows shell:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe c:\helloworld.py
```

Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\David> $process = "python.exe"
PS C:\Users\David> gwmi Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" | select CommandLine

CommandLine
-----------
C:\Python33\python.exe  C:\helloworld.py
```

---

from windows shell calling python in cygwin\bin:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\python3.2m.exe c:\helloworld.py
```

Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\David> $process = "python3.2m.exe"
PS C:\Users\David> gwmi Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" | select CommandLine

CommandLine
-----------
C:\cygwin\bin\python3.2m.exe  C:\helloworld.py
```

Comment: Well, @DeveloperGuo, I must suppose that the problem is mine. Maybe because I am working with the CygWin version of Python, instead of the native Windows one. I tried Python3, but the script is not compatible. I think the appropriate is to open a new thread asking about CygWin. Thanks you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to come from the **Python** interpreter included in official CygWin repositories (as of today, v2.7.3).
Happily, the solution itself appears to be onto the own CygWin **pgrep** command.

Assuming this command line to run the Python process:

```
c:\CygWin\bin\python2.7.exe /usr/local/bin/FunnyProgram.py
```

--> To find the process we can use `pgrep` with the `-f` option (to search for *full* path):

```
$ pgrep -f -l FunnyProgram.py
2640 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/FunnyProgram.py
```

--> To kill the process directly:

```
$ kill $(pgrep -f FunnyProgram.py)
```

I have no idea about why `ps`, `tasklist` or any other commands fail doing what `pgrep` does.

According to @DeveloperGuo, this isssue could be **solved for v3** and laters.

Saddly, Python v2 and v3 scripts are not compatibles, so I hope this thread helps anyone arriving here in search of knowledge and wishdom :-) .