# Debugging multiple dotnet programs with same dotnet.exe process name

Tags: .net-core

Given that there are two dotnet core programs: App1 and App2.
The compile output of App1 and App2 is App1.dll and App2.dll respectively.

As running dotnet application is like this,

```
dotnet.exe App1.dll
dotnet.exe App2.dll
```

when I open Attach Process dialog box in Visual Studio, they show the same dotnet.exe process name instead of App1 or App2. So I cannot distinguish App1 from App2.

Is there any recommended or better way of attaching debugger to the different dotnet core programs?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to look at the command line info for the process.

In powershell that would be like 
`Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'dotnet.exe'" | Select-Object CommandLine`

You can look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563411/how-to-get-command-line-info-for-a-process-in-powershell-or-c-sharp) for more details