# How to know from which file/dir(package) nodejs(node.exe) running on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, cmd, node-modules

Suppose multiple node package/file running multiple node server on windows machine.
So, I need all the information (complete path of the node package/file, port, host, pid, ppid ) of the file from node server is working/running(node.exe) on the machine.

Example: Two node.exe running on the machine. both are running from the different different destination (first from `"C:\Users\kuldeep.singh\Desktop\porting\v1\node1\index.js"` and another from `"C:\Users\kuldeep.singh\Desktop\porting\v2\node2\index.js"`) with different-different PPID.
I want to filter the only node process with the path of the destinations from the node process got started.

I am getting all the details like :

`[ { port: 3400,
    pid: 27200,
    ppid: 27168,
    name: 'node.exe',
    cmd: 'node  index.js',
    bin: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe' } ]`

But I am unable to get the destination path like (`"C:\Users\kuldeep.singh\Desktop\porting\v1\node1\index.js"`) from which node.exe file got run.

Currently, I am using `path` and `find-process` node module.

Please consider the windows machine while providing the solution.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to detect this as well. While I can check if node.exe is alive, I would prefer a belts & braces solution that tells me which script is currently running.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for checking if any `node.exe myscript.js` is running (or any .exe with a commandline). This answer came from mixing [How to see which Node.js scripts are currently running on the system?](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1418), [How do I find out command line arguments of a running program?](https://superuser.com/a/793555/1854155) and [How to get Command Line info for a process in PowerShell or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47801130/22669764).

In powershell run either of the following, Get-WMIObject is meant to be superseded by Get-CimInstance but both work for me on Win 11:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'node.exe'" | where {$_.CommandLine -match "script.js" } | select CommandLine
```

or:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'node.exe'" | where {$_.CommandLine -match "script.js" } | select CommandLine
```

If the process is alive with a matching command parameter you'll see a response similar to the examples below, they'll reflect the line as it was called:

```
CommandLine
-----------
node  script.js
```

or:

```
CommandLine
-----------
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"  D:\Data\myscript\script.js
```

If not you'll be back at the command prompt with no output. We can use this in a very basic script to test things, copy/paste and save as `testrunning.ps1`:

```
# Usage testrunning.ps1 exename searchstring
#       testrunning.ps1 foo.exe bar
#       testrunning.ps1 "foo.exe" "bar foo bar"
#       testrunning.ps1 "foo.exe" 
param([string]$exename,$searchstring)

# Capture output
$test = Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = `"$exename`"" | where {$_.CommandLine -match "$searchstring" } | select CommandLine | Out-String
# Very basic test, $test is empty if search returns nothing


if ($searchstring -notlike "") {
        if ($test -notlike "*$exename*" -And $test -notlike "*$searchstring*") {
            $running = 0
        } else {
            $running = 1
        }
    } else {
        if ($test -notlike "*$exename*") {
            $running = 0
        } else {
            $running = 1
        }   
    }

$string = "$exename $searchstring".Trim()

if ($running -match 0) {
        echo "`'$string'` Not Running"
        # We could do something here like restart a script or send a warning
    } else {        
        echo $test
        echo "`'$string'` is Running"
    }
```

Then run `.\testprocess.ps1 "node.exe" "server.js"` (This tests my [TamperDAV](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tamperdav) server).

I get:

```
CommandLine
-----------
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\Data\OneDrive\TamperDAV\server.js

'node.exe server.js' is Running
```

One limitation/shortcoming is that you cannot check multiple arguments (for example, my TamperDAV command is `node.exe server.js %*`) however, as long as your tested match is unique that should not be an issue. In the OP's case...

```
testprocess.ps1 "node.exe" "C:\Users\kuldeep.singh\Desktop\porting\v1\node1\index.js"
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

try to check `__filename` or `__dirname`

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_filename

Comment: right. but script is independent to these files and script is running from the another file and i only have pid, ppid, hostname  and port of node.exe and __filename or __dirname, these two will not work available data and I think if work then give only current module(script.js) information.

ex: one script file (script.js)  and two other node file(server1.js and server2.js) and by these two server file two node server is running(node.exe).
when i run the script.js file  then I want both server file full path from which node.exe file got run.

Answer (score -1):

By using the below code you can find the directory/ file

```
console.log(__filename);

console.log(__dirname);
```