# Get WMI class of a running process in windows powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-arguments, wmi, get-wmiobject

I am running a python script using "python script.py arg1 arg2 ...". I wanted to use powershell to check memory consumption of this script (process). The below command can't catch the python process. Looks like it isn't a win32_process?

```
Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "name like '%python'"
```

In this [blog by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091125-00/?p=15923), it is dealing with win32_process class. Looks like my python process is not win32_process, because the above command doesn't catch it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Command Line info for a process in PowerShell or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563411/how-to-get-command-line-info-for-a-process-in-powershell-or-c-sharp)

Comment: It does not. I tried the same command and it did not work for me. The reason could be that the python program is not a win32_process. Not sure how to find the right class for my program.

Comment: I have updated question to ask how to get WMI class of the running process. Answer to that will help me find the command line args for it.

Comment: I believe the name would be `python.exe`.

Comment: Btw get-process in powershell 7 has a commandline property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the win32_process wmi class for python, and the name has the .exe on the end, slightly different from get-process:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "name = 'python.exe'" | select name,commandline

name       commandline
----       -----------
python.exe "C:\Program Files\emacs\bin\python.exe"
```

Or

```
Get-WmiObject win32_process | ? name -eq python.exe | select name,commandline

name       commandline
----       -----------
python.exe "C:\Program Files\emacs\bin\python.exe"
```

Or in powershell 7, get-process has the commandline property:

```
get-process python | select name,commandline

Name   CommandLine
----   -----------
python "C:\Program Files\emacs\bin\python.exe"
```